# apply function - custom function returning NULL at the end

Tags: r

```
x = matrix(1:5)

func = function(x)  {
   for ( i in 1:x ) {
       print(i)
   }
}

apply(X=x, 1, func)
```

Output :

```
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
NULL
```

Why is this function generating NULL at the end ?

Answer (score 6):

By definition, an R function returns the result of the last expression to be evaluated. In this case, the expression is the entire `for` loop, which returns `NULL`. If you want to not print the null result, you can store the result in a variable (`result <- apply(...)`) or use `invisible()`:

```
invisible(apply(X=x, 1, func))
```

I don't know of a way to modify the function itself to get this behaviour, since you are calling the function through `apply()`.

By the way, why not `invisible(lapply(x,func))` ?